# Load testing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I want to create virtual traffic on my site for testing scalability using Load Testing which is provided by Visual studio 2010 Ultimate.

Is there any tutorial for Load Testing in visual studio 2010? I Googled for it but did not get any good articles or tutorials.

Could you provide me with any useful links or articles that I can use to perform Load Testing quickly and easily?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspx
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/howie_hillikers_blog/archive/2010/05/26/what-s-new-in-the-visual-studio-2010-web-performance-and-load-test-documentaion-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Also get the "Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide" from codeplex
http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/